# Skype event never goes away

Tags: linux, skype

I seem to have an "immortal" event - when I start Skype I always get an event that one of my contacts has called me. Clicking on "Mark All Viewed" will remove it, until next time I start Skype, and it's back there. This has been driving me nuts!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer from [here](http://community.skype.com/t5/Windows-desktop-client/how-to-delete-missed-call-notifications/m-p/1793107/highlight/true#M177259):

> I had this problem too, but on the Linux version.  In the end, I found that instead of using the X or the "mark all viewed", I could right click on the entry and delete it from there.  Don't know if this works for Windows as well.